# Postgresql backup script how write log

Tags: windows, postgresql, batch-file, logging, database-backups

I have this script for PostgreSQL database backup. The script makes backups of all databases except those that are passed in the array. Everything works perfectly. But I can't figure out how to output and save the results of the script to a log file. Tell me please. Thank you in advance!

```
set PGPASSWORD=Password
set BACKUPPATH=Q:\PostgresBackup
set DATETIME=%DATE:~6,4%-%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~0,2% %TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%-%TIME:~6,2%
set LOGFILE=%DATETIME%.log
set LOGPATH=E:\backup1c\log\%LOGFILE%
set PSQL=Z:\base1c\10\bin\psql.exe
set PGDUMP=Z:\base1c\10\bin\pg_dump.exe
:: dump all bases not in (test,postgres, temp*)
for /F  %%i in ( '%PSQL% -t -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres  -c "select  datname FROM pg_database WHERE datname NOT LIKE ALL (ARRAY[ 'test','postgres','temp%%']);" ')  do ( 
    echo %%i
    for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=/-:., " %%a in ( "%DATE: =0% %TIME: =0%" ) do ( 
    %PGDUMP%    -U postgres -Fc -b -v -f %BACKUPPATH%\%%i-%%c-%%b-%%a_%%d_%%e.backup %%i 2>%LOGPATH%
                                        )
    )
```

Comment: You need `1> "output.log"`, or `1>> "output.log"`, just put it in an appropriate place within your script, or at the end of the command which runs/calls it.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer! Yes I understand what. But a can't figure out in what please paste this. If I paste this in the end of this line %PGDUMP%    -U postgres -Fc -b -v -f %BACKUPPATH%\%%i-%%c-%%b-%%a_%%d_%%e.backup %%i I got error to many parameters. If I paste it a the end of the script, I've got nothing in the log.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to log the output from? There are only two lines which are outputting data, `echo %%i` and `Z:\base1c\10\bin\pg_dump.exe    -U postgres -Fc -b -v -f Q:\PostgresBackup\%%i-%%c-%%b-%%a_%%d_%%e.backup %%i`. Also you appear to be defining a variable named `now` within the for loop which you aren't using, I would suggest you move that out of the loop if you're not using it within it, and if you are, then you will require delayed expansion and you should tell us what else is there, _(especially if your're trying to log its output, as it would be part of your question)_.

Comment: I need log errors during pg_dump. Yes, your right variable now is not needed. I try like this 2>some log file,but with no luck.

Comment: Please use the **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63308763/edit)** button to include within your question your actual code as of your latest attempt, _complete with your `2>some log file` addition(s)_.

Comment: I edited script as you say. Add some variables for backup file and add output fo log. But now scrip doesnt work at all. In the log file i see this pg_dump: too many command-line arguments (first is "19-45-21.log")

Comment: I think i get it. I have to many parametrs in variable DATETIME

Comment: Well it's good that you think you've got it, but I dont believe that you're doing it correctly. You only appear to be using the `H` or `HH` portion of the `%TIME%` variable, at the time when the outer `for /F` loop is parsed. The problem with that is that it is possible that the outer `for /F` is parsed just before the turn of the hour, one or several, of the metavariables `%%a`,  `%%b`,  `%%c`,  `%%d`, or `%%e` could be incorrect. Unless absolute accuracy is required, it makes more sense to parse the date and time before your loops. Also if you're only using five tokens don't retrieve seven.

Comment: Thank you for help! I will fix my script as you say! Now i testing it and seems it working and writing output in the lig file.